# how can I make this font smaller without messing up the effects that go with it

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

this is the font:   https://codemyui.com/glowing-flicker-neon-text-effect/
I'm using this font in a table,       whenever I try to resize it messes up the text shadow and other effects, I can't use transform as it messes up its placement in the table.

Comment: You need to post the code that you are using for the table. Something else can be overriding the effects. I can edit the font-size just fine on CodePen.

Comment: I can edit the font size but only the text sizes down

Comment: please post your code or provide a fiddle of your code so that we can help you better

Comment: I can't post the code right now but I can in 1 hour

Comment: I visitied this https://codepen.io/Trinca/pen/NAvpWa and resized the font and it's text shadow and other effects are working perfectly

Comment: ok we'll be waiting for your code

Comment: I found a better alternative instead, never mind.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better alternative instead, never mind.